# What syntax is this in this function argument?

Tags: c++

I'm wondering what this empty pair of braces `{}` means when passed as a function argument? It can mean many things, so it's hard to know exactly what's going on. I mean, is it creating a `std::initializer_list`, or calling a converting (implicit) constructor?

```
#include "asio_http/http_client.h"
#include "asio_http/http_request_result.h"

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  boost::asio::io_context context;

  asio_http::http_client  client({}, context); // HERE 'client({}, context)'

  client.get([](asio_http::http_request_result result) { std::cout << result.get_body_as_string(); }, "www.google.com");

  context.run();
}
```

Comment: The first parameter in the `http_client` constructor is a [temporary variable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime#Temporary_object_lifetime) being [default initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization).

Comment: @user4581301 How does the compiler know what to construct a temporary of? It's just empty braces. Like, a temporary would be http_client client( Foo{}, context); What does {} mean here?

Comment: If I'm reading [this](https://github.com/juliobg/asio_http/blob/master/interface/asio_http/http_client.h) correctly (and I've found the right code), it will be a `http_client_settings` instance. The compiler will infer the type from the type of the argument from the type of the parameter and perform the rest of the magic for you.

Comment: Suppose you have a function `void func(int i, float f, std::string s){/*…*/}`. Then, calling `func({}, {}, {});` will construct the a zero `int`, a zero `float`, and an empty `std::string` respectively. The same logic applies to any other types of parameters.

Comment: @Zebrafish `{}` will be come a default initializer of whatever type `client` takes as the first argument.

Comment: @user4581301 The `{}` does not cause any temporary to be created. It directly initializes the function parameter.

Comment: @user17732522  that comes as quite a surprise. What does it do instead? Ah. The edit clears that up. Thank you.

Comment: Is http_client client( Foo{}, context); equivalent to http_client client( {}, context); You say it directly initialises it, but I would bet that a copy constructor is called, meaning there's a temporary, are you sure?

Comment: @Zebrafish Ignoring overload resolution differences and if `Foo` is the same (non-reference) type as that of the constructor parameter, then in C++17 and later `{}` and `Foo{}` are exactly identical, except if `Foo` behaves differently on copy-list-initialization (`= {}`) than it does on direct-list-initialization (`Foo{}`), which may happen e.g. if there are `explicit` constructors. Either way in C++17 it is guaranteed that there is only one object, the function parameter, no temporary.

Comment: In this case, again assuming I found the right documentation, `const http_client_settings& settings` will need a temporary to bind to (so no copy required), but if it was `http_client_settings settings`, `settings` would be directly initialized. Even if there were a temporary technically involved, the compiler would elide the copy.

Comment: @user4581301 Yes, if the parameter is a reference type, then a temporary object needs to be materialized and the temporary object is copy-list-initialized from `{}` instead. In any case C++17 guarantees that there is exactly one object, either the function parameter object or the temporary object.

Answer (score 2):

It is a *braced-init-list* with (almost) exact same meaning as in normal initialization of variables, except that it is always copy-list-initialization instead of direct-list-initialization, i.e. it behaves as if there was a `=` before the *braced-init-list*.

I.e. `{}` in the function argument means that the corresponding function parameter (let's say of type `P` with name `p`) will be initialized as if it had been defined as a variable like this:

```
P p = {};
```

---

This is also not special to *braced-init-list* arguments. If the function argument is an expression `E` instead, then it still behaves as if `p` is (non-list-)copy-initialized like the variable

```
P p = E;
```

---

If `P` is a reference type that can bind to rvalues (i.e. rvalue reference or `const` lvalue reference), then this initialization may, as usual, cause the creation of a temporary object to bind the reference to.

The lifetime rules for this temporary are the same as for other temporaries created in the caller's context, i.e. it lives until the end of the full-expression containing the function call. This is different from the behavior of the variable initialization shown above, which would cause the temporary to live as long as `p` instead.

---

There are however some special template argument deduction rules and overload resolution aspects to consider as well, in particular because the *braced-init-list* doesn't have a type like an expression as argument would have.

I will not go into detail here, but roughly, a *braced-init-list* can only deduce against `std::initializer_list` or built-in array function parameters (and only if the list is non-empty) and overload resolution for a *braced-init-list* will prefer `std::initializer_list` parameters over other types.

The above is the behavior after overload resolution.

Comment: In particular, of the cases you glossed over, it is a viable match to a `std::initializer_list` parameter   (I don't know the ranking rules offhand!)